# Indexing Original Data by Its Variance

Tags: r

I am trying to sort through a dataset, take the variance of each row, and then create a new object containing the top variances of each row.  For example, as far as I can get is:

```
data(iris)
#The fifth column in iris is a string vector so I will exclude it'
newvar<-apply(iris[1:4],1,var)
newvar.srt<-sort(newvar, decreasing = TRUE)
```

So far so good?  My question now is how can I go back to the iris dataset and create a new object that contains only the rows of say the top 30 variances?

I thought about comparing newvar to newvar.srt[1:30] to try and index the original columns and then index them into a new object as newobject<-iris[top30.variance.rows,] but can’t get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `order`. Try this:

```
data(iris)
nv <- apply(iris[1:4], MARGIN = 1, FUN = var)
n_rows = 30
data_sample = head( iris[order(nv, decreasing=TRUE), ], n_rows)
```

Comment: After testing, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for!  Thank you.

Comment: Just curious (because I reallllly like learning), you used the order() function within the x part of the index (e.g. iris[order(),])  could you explain this?  What happened if you used it in the y axis/column?

Comment: `order` sends back a vector of indices. Try `order(nv, decreasing=TRUE)` to understand what it does.